# How to convert getTime to seconds?

Tags: java, jdbc, timestamp

Can you please help in matter:

I have defined a variable which is:

```
Time from_time = rs.getTime("nfrm_time");
```

and it will read the values 7:15:00

How to convert this type to seconds?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Call [`getTime`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#getTime()) to get the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970. Divide by 1000 to get it in seconds:

```
long unixTime = from_time.getTime() / 1000;
```

To get the number of seconds since 00:00 of the *current* day, use the

```
Calendar c = Calendar();
c.setTime(from_time);
long daySeconds = (c.get(Calendar.SECONDS) +
                   c.get(Calendar.MINUTES) * 60 +
                   c.get(Calendar.HOURS) * 3600);
```

Comment: @maas Fortunately, converting milliseconds to seconds is really easy: Just divide by 1000. Added text to the code that already did this.

Comment: It converted the time to an incorrect value. The time is 00:04:00 which is 4 minutes and in the conversion it showed -10560000

Comment: @maas That's because UNIX time calculates the number of seconds from 1970 till now, instead of the start of the current day till now. Updated with a solution that calculates the number of seconds in a day.

Answer (score 3):

`long seconds = rs.getTime("nfrm_time").getTime() / 1000`

Here's the explanation:

`rs.getTime("nfrm_time")` returns `java.sql.Time` which is actually a sub class of `java.util.Date`.

`java.util.Date.getTime()` returns time in milli seconds which we divide by `1000` to get seconds.

**Note:**

If you're looking for duration instead,

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(rs.getTime("nfrm_time")); // set to the time returned by resultset
cal.set(0, 0, 0); // reset the year, month and date fields

Calendar cal2 = Calendar.getInstance();

cal2.set(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0); // reset all the fields, including time

long duration = ((cal.getTimeInMillis() - cal2.getTimeInMillis()) / 1000) + 1;
```

Comment: It converted the time to an incorrect value. I am having a value of 00:04:00 which is 4 minutes and in the conversion it showed (-10560000 )

Comment: Updated my answer. Try with that.

Comment: I tried but did not success   it is showing an error ---Time time1 = Time.valueOf(rs.getTime("abs_hours")); valueOf(java.lang.String) in java.sql.Time cannot be applied to (java.sql.Time)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
from_time.getTime() / 1000
```

This might work since:

> The date components should be set to the "zero epoch" value of January 1, 1970 and should not be accessed.

This means that the date part is always the *epoch* day, which means the `Time` instance is represented by the number of milliseconds since the beginning of the day.

Comment: It converted the time to an incorrect value. The time is 00:04:00 which is 4 minutes and in the conversion it showed -10560000

Comment: It converted the time to an incorrect value. The time is 00:04:00 which is 4 minutes and in the conversion it showed -10560000

Answer (score 1):

java.sql.Time inherits from java.util.Date which has a method getTime() which returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.

So `from_time.getTime()/1000` should do the trick.

Comment: It converted the time to an incorrect value. The time is 00:04:00 which is 4 minutes and in the conversion it showed -10560000 –

Answer (score 1):

Cleaner way is 
`Time from_time = Math.round(rs.getTime("nfrm_time")/1000);`

Answer (score -1):

To get the milliseconds:

```
long ms = from_time.getTime();
```